# Floating point numbers should not be tested for equality (S1244) triggered incorrectly for C# code?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We recently encountered something strange with one of the SonarQube rules during the validation of our C# code.
Floating point numbers should not be tested for equality (S1244)

We understand why this rule exists and that we should correct the errors, but we can't figure out why some of our code is correct and other parts not.

```
double valueToCheck;    
if(valueToCheck > 0f || valueToCheck < 0)
{
   do something
}
```

The first example does not trigger the S1244 error but

```
double valueToCheck;    
if(valueToCheck > 0f || valueToCheck < 0f)
{
   do something
}
```

does.

When we looked at this ourselves we thought that the first example should still give the error, because the second part in the if statement still does not use a float.

However apparently that does not matter. But when we then add the second float to if statement, it is incorrect again.

Has anyone encountered this before, or could explain why the first example should be correct? 
Or could this be a bug?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the language.

Comment: I edited the text to include that we develop in C#. Also added the tag C#

Comment: Does anything change when you use 0d instead of 0f? Because float and double are not the same in .net (even though autoconversion probably happens)

Comment: Changing from 0f to 0d gives the same error.

Comment: It's plainly a bug in SonarQube. I'd address your question to the authors of this software.

Answer (score -1):

You have a different result because when comparing < and > to 0f you do make floating comparison but in the first example you do a float and an int comparison (so you are not strictly getting the result of a floating equality to 0).